# Driver not loaded mySql

Tags: mysql, pyqt5

Estoy usando Pycharm con Python3.9 y PyQt 5.15.2 y QSqlDatabase
He seguido las instrucciones en https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/sql-driver.html#qmysql How to Build the QMYSQL Plugin on Windows. He usado el compilador mingw81_64
El fichero qsqlmysql.dll se ha generado y lo he copiado a  PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers a mi entorno virtual.
También he copiado el fichero libmydql.dll a PyQt5/Qt5/bin a mi entorno virtual.
Si ejecuto database.drivers() obtengo lo siguiente
['QSQLITE', 'QMARIADB', 'QMYSQL', 'QMYSQL3', 'QODBC', 'QODBC3', 'QPSQL', 'QPSQL7']
Me da el siguiente error
"Driver not loaded"
También he intentado descargar el fichero qsqlmysql.dll de https://github.com/weldermarcosxd/pyqt5-mysql/blob/master/Lib/site-packages/PyQt5/Qt/plugins/sqldrivers/qsqlmysql.dll
pero me da el mismo error
Estoy usando esta base de datos https://remotemysql.com/

```
class Login(QWidget):
def __init__(self):
    super().__init__()
    self.init_widgets()
    self.set_styles()
    self.connect()

def connect(self):
    server = 'remotemysql.com'
    database_name = '****'
    user_name = '****'
    password = '****'

    self.database = QSqlDatabase.addDatabase("QMYSQL")
    self.database.setHostName(server)
    self.database.setDatabaseName(database_name)
    self.database.setUserName(user_name)
    self.database.setPassword(password)
    ok = self.database.open()
    if ok:
        print('Success')
    else:
        print(self.database.lastError().text())


app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Login()
window.show()
app.exec_()
```

Comment: @padaleiana se la he traducido :)

Comment: @JavierG.Raya no podés traducirla, debe ser el OP quien la traduzca. Si revisás tu edición, tuvo 2 rechazos por el mismo motivo. Hay varias preguntas en [meta] al respecto, una de ellas es [esta](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/4445/es-%c3%banicamente-responsabilidad-del-op-traducir-su-pregunta).

Comment: Vale entonces no puedo traducir las preguntas ni tocar su código vales muchas gracias @padaleiana me lo anoto para la próxima